# I am receiving a pluggable.php warning sign on my only http:// page

Tags: php, redirect, http, warnings, troubleshooting

I just recently shared a link to my site using he http to my site: http://thechronicalist.com but instead of redirecting, i just displays this:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thecmltm/public_html/index.php:1) in /home/thecmltm/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1281

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thecmltm/public_html/index.php:1) in /home/thecmltm/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1284

I have searched all over the web but they all talk about function.php or wp_configure.php but that is not what my problem is. I have tried editing the index.php but nothing is wrong with it.

When i search with https://thechronicalist.com, nothing happens and my blog posts and pictures all appear!

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `headers already sent` message means that something -- a plugin or a theme, usually -- is sending output before it's meant to. Often this is due to whitespace appearing in a file after the closing `?>` tag, which can make it hard to find the culprit.

The fact that `pluggable.php` is mentioned tells me that it's most likely a plugin that's replacing some of WordPress's pluggable functionality. Often this is related to user management, though there are other pluggable functions.

The usual advice in this situation is to turn off all your plugins and switch to a default theme. If the problem goes away, then the culprit is a plugin or the theme you were using. Turn them back on one by one until the problem recurs. Now you've found the culprit. You will then know who you need to reach out to for support.

[Pluggable Functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) -- it's possible, too, that there's a plugin attempting to do HTTP->HTTPS redirection, and that might be causing you grief.

Comment: Good point. My eye skipped to the end of the error message, where `pluggable.php` was mentioned.